# MongoDB - Difference between getCollection(String name) and getCollectionFromString(String collectionName)?

Tags: java, mongodb, database

Can someone please highlight for me the difference between getCollection(String name) and getCollectionFromString(String collectionName) as documented in the MongoDB DB Java api?

```
public DBCollection getCollectionFromString(String collectionName)
Returns a collection matching a given string.
Parameters: collectionName - the name of the collection
Returns: the collection
```

and

```
public DBCollection getCollection(String name)
Gets a collection with a given name.
Parameters: name - the name of the collection to return
Returns: the collection
```

An illustration with example would be most helpful. 
(pulled from https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from Karl Seguin in this [**forum**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/ll0mf1uqMFo):

> A collection can be identified by a namespace, "db.collection". 
>   getCollectionFromString gets the collection for that sort of
>   namespace. getCollection gets it for just the raw collection.
>
> The places where you'd need/use getCollectionFromString have more to
>   do with building some type of mongodb management tool or possibly a
>   CMS which spans multiple databases...that sort of dynamic driven
>   system. getCollection is probably more typical for most apps.

Another **[explanation](http://osdir.com/ml/mongodb-user/2012-01/msg01517.html)**:

> I think which you use will really depend on what you are expecting
>   your  users to enter.
>
> If they don't know anything about all the databases, then using 
>   getCollection() makes sense...which I'm thinking would be the case.
>
> If it's a truly dynamic system and the user might say "get me the
>   users  from the database app1" then the getCollectionFromStirng might
>   make sense.
>
> However, I'd argue that int the 2nd case, it would be better to simply
>   have  two fields: Database and Collection. That way it's more explicit
>   and  simpler to deal with. Why should your users know that database
>   and  collection are dot separated in MongoDB?

An **[example](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-get-collection-from-database/)** to illustrate `getCollection(String s)`:

```
package com.example.core;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Set;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;

/**
 * Java : Get collection from MongoDB
 * 
 */
public class GetCollectionApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("yourdb");

        // get list of collections
        Set<String> collections = db.getCollectionNames();

        for (String collectionName : collections) {
            System.out.println(collectionName);
        }

        // get a single collection
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("yourCollection");
        System.out.println(collection.toString());

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MongoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**[Implementation](http://osdir.com/ml/mongodb-user/2010-08/msg01676.html)** of `getCollectionFromString(String s)`

```
public DBCollection getCollectionFromString(String s){
     DBCollection foo = null;

     while (s.contains(".")){
          int idx = s.indexOf(".");
          String b = s.substring(0, idx);
          s = s.substring(idx + 1);
          foo = getCollection(b);
     }

     if (foo != null)
         return foo;
     return getCollection(s);
 }
```